# Boost serialization - the meaning of the content in a .txt file

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I would like to save objects from a parent class in a text file and then be able to load the objects. The problem is that all the objects are pointers so only the addresses of the objects could be saved but not the objects themselves. The code below compiles but I'm not sure what the meaning of the information in the .txt file is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <sstream>

class Gear {
  public:
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version) { ar & v; }

    void setV (const double& _v) { v = _v; }
    double getV () { return v; }

    void status () { std::cout << "v = " << v << std::endl; }

  private:
    double v;
};

class Car {
  public:
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned int version) {
      ar & hp;
      ar & x;
    }
    void setHP (const int& _hp) { hp = _hp; }
    void setGear (Gear* _Gear) { x = _Gear; }
    void status () { std::cout << "hp = " << hp << " Gear with v = " << x->getV() << std::endl; }

  private:
    int hp;
    Gear *x;
};

int main() {
  // Define new Gear:
  Gear* g = new Gear();
  g->setV(2.5);
  g->status();

  // Expectation is Car sets up the Gear.
  Car c;
  c.setHP(80);
  c.setGear(g);
  c.status();




  std::ofstream outputStream;
  outputStream.open("Car.txt");
  boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(outputStream);
  outputArchive << c;
  outputStream.close();

  Car b;
  std::ifstream inputStream;
  inputStream.open("Car.txt", std::ifstream::in);
  boost::archive::text_iarchive inputArchive(inputStream);
  inputArchive >> b;
  b.status();
  inputStream.close();
  return 0;


}
```

And in the file I get:

```
22 serialization::archive 10 0 0 80 1 1 0
0 2.5
```

What does all of this mean? 2.5 makes sense but the others I'm not sure of.

I also used sstream instead of io/fstream (replace code from std::ofstream outputStream; to inputStream.close(); with this code below):

```
    std::stringstream ss;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa{ss};
    oa << c;

    Car b;
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia{ss};
    ia >> b;
    b.status();
```

With this code I get (after running ./a.out with the command g++ -std=c++11 boost_serial.cpp -lboost_serialization
):

```
v = 2.5
hp = 80 Gear with v = 2.5
hp = 80 Gear with v = 2.5
```

Comment: I will guess you copied this code from someplace, and now... You would have to dig into the serializer for some of those values. But you don't need to know to use it. I see `80`, the horse power. The serializer will store the likes of the size of the classes and what other information it needs to stream. And it prints what it does because that is in your source code.

Comment: Why do you guess I copied this code? Yes I see 80 and 2.5 as well. But my question was what does all of the other stuff mean and (another question) how can I save the data to a .txt file instead of getting 22 serialization...etc. in the .txt file.

Comment: Hi, like I said, *The serializer will store the likes of the size of the classes and what other information it needs to stream.* It is not meant to be a streamer of what data you want it to save, it has a job of saving data it can restore to objects. If you want to save data in your format, write it to your own output to std::ofstream.

Comment: Okay so the code  `boost::archive::text_iarchive ia{ss}; ia >> b;`  is probably then best when regarding the serialization right? To your last point, I did use std::ofstream to do just that but I'm getting these two lines instead. Could you give me another tip how to save the data?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your objective. If it is to save and restore the values of objects, you have done that and you don't need to know the details of what boost::archive does. If you want to output the data and not use it to restore, that is something else. If you want to output the data in your own format and use it to restore, that is also something else. Personally I use XML for archiving so I don't have to deal with versioning. And that is something else.

Comment: Yea I'm fairly new with all of this so bare with me. Essentially, I want to be able to store specific items from a class in a .txt file (the end goal is to save them in a binary file because the .txt file will get very big) and then be able to restore/load them.

Comment: Then it sounds like boost::archive would be suitable for you. Especially as it is easily moved from text to binary archiving. Try to get it right by the time you are saving what you must restore. I find versioning a pain. Back when I started it was with MFC archiving. It became a nightmare for me and why I moved to XML archiving. It really depends on what kind of data you are really saving.

Comment: The types of data would be mostly basic data types (double, int, string) std::vector, std::map, arma::mat, arma::sp_mat (arma:: are matrices which I will also need to save via boost::archive) and some made classes. BTW thanks for taking the time.

Comment: So my questions is: Why can't I currently save the data in the .txt?

Comment: I just tested your code as what I saw from what you posted is working. You are streaming `a` out to a file and then steaming that file back into `b`. I was surprised that boost::archive even dealt with your pointer to Gear. I thought that would be a problem. I'd love to write an answer but your last question is not correct. You are saving the object to a file and restoring with what you have.

Comment: Well essentially what I want is to save information to a .txt file (later to a binary file) and then load that information at a later time. So the saving and loading works already. Hm, you make a good point. Maybe it's not even worth knowing what the .txt file looks like since all I want in the end is to load the content. Yea boost serialization also deals with pointers.

Comment: It is that you had a bare pointer. You really should be using a managed, shared, pointer.

Comment: Very true. We use smart and shared pointers in our code. This was just for a simpler example. Though, that is my next step -- seeing how Boost Seri works with smart/shared pointers.